# Application Server and Web Server running on same hardware/physical server

Tags: sql-server, apache, tomcat, soap

I have a conceptual design question. I'm building an application/platform that will consist of a server, possibly running Apache Tomcat w/ a MySQL database, and several client applications (such as native iPhone apps, android apps, blackberry apps). Communication between the client applications and the server will be handled via SOAP, or XML-RPC (also trying to figure this out).

All of the above I'm reasonably comfortable with, but the last part of my plan is to create web/browser based client interface to the platform. And this is where I run into my question, should I install Apache Web Server on my same physical server and build a PHP application that invokes RPC's on the Application Server (Tomcat, running on same physical machine)? Does this type of design pattern make sense? Or should I stick with one type of server software for all possible client applications, including the web/browser based application? Thanks!

Comment: This is mostly a performance issue really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the web server and app server ought to be separate.  I'd make the database separate from the app server too, if I could.

The reason I like the web server to be separate is that it's usually in between two firewalls.  The app server lives inside the second firewall in the "safe" network.

Comment: so the web application will be handled by the separate web server (which will access the app server) and my other client applications (blackberry, iphone, android) will all access the app server directly?

Comment: Nope, requests to the web server are proxied into the app server.

Comment: I think, in the context of AWS set up, the argument is not valid if the webservers are fronted by AWS load balancer with WAF (Web Application Firewall). See [Elastic Load Balancing Features](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/).